# How to translate package content?

Tags: r, localization, internationalization, package

I want to have error messages, warnings and other user feedback from my package available in multiple languages.  (R can translate the contents of `message`, `warning`, `stop`, `gettext`, and `ngettext`.)

There is advice on how to do this in these documents:

1. The [Internationalization](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Internationalization) section of Writing R Extensions.
2. The [Localization of messages](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-admin.html#Localization-of-messages) section of R Installation and Administration.
3. The [Translations](http://developer.r-project.org/Translations30.html) ([R < 3.0.0](http://developer.r-project.org/Translations.html)) page of the R Developer guidance.

The [`mgcv`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/index.html) and [`Rcmdr`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcmdr/index.html) ([po](https://github.com/cran/Rcmdr/tree/master/po) dir) packages have translations, providing examples of how to do things.

Nevertheless, I'm struggling to get things working.  Here's a reproducible package example:

On Windows you need to download and extract [gettext-tools](http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/Rtools/goodies/gettext-tools.zip), and add the location to your Windows `PATH` environment variable.

```
library(roxygen2)
library(devtools)
library(tools)

# Create the directories to hold the package content
Vectorize(dir.create)(c("test", "test/R", "test/man", "test/po"))

# Write the package DESCRIPTION file
cat(
  'Package: test
Title: Test pkg
Description: Investigate how to translate content
Version: 0.0-1
Date: 2015-03-17
Author: Richard Cotton
Maintainer: Richard Cotton <a@b.com>
License: Unlimited',
  file = "test/DESCRIPTION"
)

# Create a function go to into the package, plus its documentation
cat(
  "#' Translatable messages
#' Some strings to be translated.
#' @param n A natural number.
#' @export
translatable <- function(n)
{
  message('faucet')
  cat(gettext('napkin'), '\n')
  cat(ngettext(n, 'one', 'many', domain = 'R-test'), '\n')
}",
  file = "test/R/translatable.R"
)

# Create the master translation file (American English)
xgettext2pot("test", "test/po/R-test.pot")

# Alter the master file to make British English and French translations
en <- readLines("test/po/R-test.pot")
en_gb <- en
en_gb[which(en_gb == 'msgid "faucet"') + 1] <- 'msgid "tap"'
en_gb[which(en_gb == 'msgid "napkin"') + 1] <- 'msgid "serviette"'
writeLines(en_gb, "test/po/R-en_GB.po")

fr <- en
fr[which(fr == 'msgid "faucet"') + 1] <- 'msgid "robinet"'
fr[which(fr == 'msgid "napkin"') + 1] <- 'msgid "serviette"'
fr[which(fr == 'msgid        "one"') + 2] <- 'msgstr[0]    "un"'
fr[which(fr == 'msgid_plural "many"') + 2] <- 'msgstr[1]    "beaucoup"'
writeLines(fr, "test/po/R-fr.po")

# Build and install the package
pkg_file <- build("test")
install.packages(pkg_file, repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Change your OS locale to `English (United States)` (under Windows 7, it's in Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Formats -> Format) and restart R.

You should see the default text:

```
library(test)
translatable(1)
## faucet
## napkin 
## one
translatable(2)
## faucet
## napkin 
## many
```

Now change your locale to `English (United Kingdom)` or to `French (France)`, restart R, and rerun the example.  I expected the text to change, but it doesn't.

`Sys.getlocale()` reports a change in my locale, so that is definitely working.

`capabilities("NLS")` returns `TRUE`, so natural language support is switched on.

With a French locale, this example adapted from the `mgcv::bam` help page gives me a French error message, so the problem is with how I've generated the package.

```
library(mgcv)
dat <- gamSim(1,n=25000,dist="normal",scale=20)
bs <- "cr";k <- 12
b <- bam(
  y ~ s(x0,bs=bs)+s(x1,bs=bs)+s(x2,bs=bs,k=k)+s(x3,bs=bs),
  data   = dat, 
  family = list(family = NULL)
)
## Erreur dans bam(y ~ s(x0, bs = bs) + s(x1, bs = bs) + s(x2, bs = bs, k = k) +  : 
##   famille non reconnue
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Thomas In the example, I create the files `po/R-en_GB.po` and `po/R-fr.po`.  It is possible that their content is incorrect, though I can't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't taken the step to compile and install your translations. And your .po files have problems.

Here's a working `R-fr.po` file for your example:

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: R 3.1.2\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: bugs.r-project.org\n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2015-03-17 09:46\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: fr\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n > 1);\n"

msgid "faucet"
msgstr "robinet"

msgid "napkin"
msgstr "serviette"

msgid        "one"
msgid_plural "many"
msgstr[0]    "un"
msgstr[1]    "beaucoup"
```

Note that you had `msgid` where you should have `msgstr`. You also did not specify the language, or the plural forms, and the "charset" variable threw an error during compilation.

Once you have the correct file, follow the directions under ["preparing and installing a translation"](http://developer.r-project.org/Translations.html). Specifically, from the command line do the following:

```
mkdir test/inst/po/fr/LC_MESSAGES
msgfmt -c --statistics -o test/inst/po/fr/LC_MESSAGES/R-test.mo R-test.po
```

This will throw some errors and warnings if there are problems. If not, it should give a confirmation message.

Then rebuild the package and install it, and then try everything again:

```
library("test")
translatable(1)
## faucet
## napkin
## one 
translatable(2)
## faucet
## napkin 
## many 
Sys.setenv(LANG = "fr")
translatable(1)
## robinet
## serviette
## un 
> translatable(2)
## robinet
## serviette
## beaucoup
```

Note, you don't need to change your OS language. You can just set the `LANG` environment variable to get the message translations.

On a related note, I find this process really annoying, so it's on my medium-term to-do list to create a package ([this one, specifically](https://github.com/leeper/msgtools)) that I hope will simplify the process.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately I'm still unable to get translated messages.  I fixed `msgid` -> `msgstr`; fixed the charset in the `pot` & `po` files; added Language and Plural lines in the `po` files.  I created `LC_MESSAGES` dirs and ran `msgfmt` on each one.  They returned without warning, claiming that translations had been created.

Comment: There are are couple of points I'm not totally clear on: I ran `msgfmt` on my source dir, not the built version in the library.  Is this correct?  Why don't `mgcv`/`Rcmdr` have  these extra `LC_MESSAGES` dirs?  Also, is the `LANG` env var value OS-specific?  I tried `Sys.setenv(LANG = "fr")` and Windows-style `Sys.setenv(LANG = "French_France.1252")`.

Comment: I've just re-run this on a Linux machine and I still can't see translations, so my stupidity is not OS-specific.

Comment: To answer my own question, `LANG` is not OS-specific; the `mgcv` example in the original question works using `Sys.setenv(LANG = "fr")`.  It's just "where do I run `msgfmt`?" that is my big source of unclarity.

Comment: @RichieCotton I'm not an expert on this, but it worked to run `msgfmt` on the source directory before building the package. Then, once installed, it produced working translations for me. (I'm running this all on Windows, so there may be differences in behavior across OS's that I'm not aware of.)

Comment: Also, mgcv and Rcmdr do have inst/po directories in their source. You won't see it in the binary, though. I'm ignorant of exactly what's happening to those directories during the build process.

Comment: Aah.  That's me not being careful. I missed that you need two separate `po` directories: `pkgroot/po` for the `.pot` and `.po` files, and `pkgroot/inst/po` for the `LC_MESSAGES` directories.  Problem solved.  Thanks for your extra effort on this.